# Problems with creating 2D table of new type node PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have error in my code

> PLS-00540: Object not supported in this context

The problem is that i somehow can not make 2D array of type that i have declared. When i look at examples of types and how to put values, everything is ok, but it's not. I don't know why. The problem is with my type node.

Have any ideas?

```
declare
type node as object
(
v_value     int,
v_x         int,
v_y         int,
is_visited  int,
s_way       varchar(50)
);

  type matrix_array is table of node;
  type matrix_type is table of matrix_array;
  matrix matrix_type := matrix_type();
  cursor c_matrix is
    select g.id, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7 from table t;

  v_value int;
  v_id    int;
  v_1     int;
  v_2     int;
  ...
  v_7     int;
begin
  for i in 1 .. 7 loop
    insert into table
      (id, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
    values
      (i,
       round(dbms_random.value(low => 1, high => 6)),
       ...
       round(dbms_random.value(low => 1, high => 6)));
  end loop;

  open c_matrix;
  matrix:=matrix_type();
  matrix.extend(7);
  for i in 1 .. 7 loop

    matrix(i):=matrix_array();
    matrix(i).extend(7);
    fetch c_matrix
      into v_id, v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6, v_7;

    matrix(i)(1) :=node( v_1, i,  1, 0, '');
    ...
    matrix(i)(7) := node( v_7, i,  7, 0, '');
   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your `node` type from outside the PL/SQL block:

```
create or replace type node as object
(
    v_value     int,
    v_x         int,
    v_y         int,
    is_visited  int,
    s_way       varchar(50)
);

declare
  type matrix_array is table of node;
  type matrix_type is table of matrix_array;
  matrix matrix_type := matrix_type();
  cursor c_matrix is
    select id, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7 from tableT;
  ...
begin
  ...
end;
```

Comment: I swear i tried that way and it doesn't works! You're magician!